# How to set CellSize, MinSpacing and SectionInset of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How can I set CellSize, MinSpacing and SectionInset of UICollectionView on "code"?

[image]

It is within the red frame of the image.

Comment: Do one thing `cmd+right Click` on UICollectionView dataSource and delegate method... you will find there all the methods to create programatically

Comment: @V_rohit Thanks for comments. OMG... I found all method for CollectionView. Really thx XDDDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all this are properties of flow layout which we have to set before collection view start layout cells this can also be set programatically by

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

now you can use above `layout` variable to set all the parameters that you set through attribute inspector

Comment: Thanks for answer. i wrote this code, then all layout property was displayed XDDDD

Answer (score 0):

You should use UICollectionViewFlowLayout
Use the below code for reference.

```
let cellSide: CGFloat = yourCustomCellSide
let leftOrRightMargin: CGFloat = yourCustomSideMargin
let sizeRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let deviceWidth = sizeRect.size.width
let availableWidth = deviceWidth - (cellSide * 4)

let customFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
customFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
customFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: leftOrRightMargin, bottom: 10, right: leftOrRightMargin)
customFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
customFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = availableWidth/4
customFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSide, height: cellSide)
yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = customFlowLayout
```